# Cassandra min and max is not working on non partition key

Tags: cassandra

I am not able to execute standard aggregate function on non partition key. I am trying to calculate min and max for a particular partition not on the entire dataset. Still its not working .

table :

```
CREATE TABLE testminmax (
   id int,
   user_id text,
   iddate int,
   a double,
   b double,
   c double,
   d double,
   e double,
   f double,
   PRIMARY KEY (id, user_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (user_id ASC)
```

My cql is `select min(a) as min, max(a) as max from testminmax where id =1`

I am getting the below error

`2017-05-04 17:06:55 [WARNING ] [cassandra.protocol.decode_messag:1087] Server warning: Read 1041 live rows and 100001 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM testminmax WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 5000 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)`

`cassandra.ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE', 'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1, 'required_responses': 1}`

Comment: Oh oh...100k tombstones... Houston we have a problem here... do you really think the problem is the query?

Comment: @xmas79 so 100k tombstones is the issue here?

Comment: If your cluster is a dev environment or something, try to increase your `tombstone_warn_threshold` in `$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra.yaml` to make sure the query itself is working. Or drop and recreate your keyspace/table (i.e. tombstones are gone) and try your query again.

Comment: @curiousguy yes they are...